# Getting error while retrieving data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for android development.

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase real time database.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
                Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                // ..
            }
        };
        database_ref.addValueEventListener(postListener);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Class 'Anonymous class derived from ValueEventListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onCancelled(DatabaseError)' in 'ValueEventListener'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be pretty much clear. Your IDE must be giving you the error that you have only overridden `OnDataChanged()` but not `onCancelled()`.

A sample for getting realtime changes in Realtime Database is:

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    // ..
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // Getting Post failed, log a message
    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
}};  mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

*Code snippet from official docs here - [Read and Write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)*

Comment: Now I am getting:
Cannot resolve symbol 'Post'

Comment: `Post` is just a java POJO object and is just used as an example. I recommend you to go through the following official getting started guide on android: [Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start)

Answer (score 1):

You have overridden only onDataChange()-method, you must override onCancelled()-method as well.

Answer (score 0):

ValueEventListener has 2 methods, 1st is onDataChange(), 2nd is onCancelled. add this in your ValueEventListener:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            // ..
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        //onCancelled
        }
    };
    database_ref.addValueEventListener(postListener);
}
```

}

Comment: Now I am getting: Cannot resolve symbol 'Post'